# How to manage classes architecture in a complex gui application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am writing an application that requires a large amount of swing GUI components.

when I put the inner class event handlers in separate files I have trouble accessing the components of my main class.

I am having a lot of trouble organizing the class. Is there a methodology to organize and neatly layout class architecture?

In addition, I have numerous anonymous and inner classes and my main class has become bloated.

how to manage my gui classes so that the event handling is easy in a way that it can call other application classes objects

```
public class MainScreen extends JFrame {

    // Variables declaration                     
    private JTree fileTree;
    private JScrollPane fileTreeScroll;
    private JSplitPane horSplit;
    private JTabbedPane textAreaPane;
    private JTabbedPane outputPane;
    private JSplitPane mainSplit;
    private JEditorPane textEditor;
    private JScrollPane textScroll;
    private JLabel log;

    private Controller controller;
    private String projectName;

    public static final String APP_NAME = "Smart Coder";
    public static final String IMAGE_PATH = "/ImageResources/";
    public static final int maxWidth = 1280;
    public static final int maxHeight = 720;
    public static final int minWidth = 800;
    public static final int minHeight = 450;
    public static final int divLen = 300;
    public static final int divLen2 = 150;

    protected JTextArea editor;
    javax.swing.JFrame frame;
    protected JFileChooser fileChooser;
    protected File currentFile;

    protected boolean textChanged = false;
    protected JToolBar toolBar;

    // End of variables declaration 
    public MainScreen() {
        super(APP_NAME);
        setSize(minWidth, minHeight);
        //DefaultSyntaxKit.initKit();
        jsyntaxpane.DefaultSyntaxKit.initKit();

        controller = new Controller();

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        mainSplit = new JSplitPane();
        outputPane = new JTabbedPane();
        horSplit = new JSplitPane();
        fileTreeScroll = new JScrollPane();
        fileTree = new JTree();
        textAreaPane = new JTabbedPane();
        textScroll = new JScrollPane();
        textEditor = new JEditorPane();
        log = new JLabel("Status : ");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(maxWidth, maxHeight));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(minWidth, minHeight));

        mainSplit.setDividerLocation(divLen);
        mainSplit.setOrientation(javax.swing.JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        mainSplit.setToolTipText("Drag to change size.");
        mainSplit.setBottomComponent(outputPane);
        horSplit.setDividerLocation(divLen2);

        fileTreeScroll.setViewportView(fileTree);

        horSplit.setLeftComponent(fileTreeScroll);

        horSplit.setRightComponent(textAreaPane);

        mainSplit.setLeftComponent(horSplit);

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        editor = new JTextArea();
        textScroll.add(editor);

        JMenuBar menuBar = createMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        getContentPane().add(log, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        try {
            File dir = (new File(".")).getCanonicalFile();
            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(dir);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

        updateEditor();
        //newDocument();

        WindowListener wndCloser = new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Action event of window closing.");
                if (!promptToSave()) {
                    return;
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };

        addWindowListener(wndCloser);
        getContentPane().add(mainSplit);
        frame = this;
        pack();
    }

    protected JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.setMnemonic('f');

//        JMenu newMenu = new JMenu("New");
//        newMenu.setMnemonic('n');
        // Action for New Project
        ImageIcon iconNewPro = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "newpack.png"));
        Action actionNewProject = new MyAction("New Project", iconNewPro, KeyEvent.VK_P,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK + InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
        fileMenu.add(actionNewProject);
//        newMenu.add(actionNewProject);

        // Action for New File
        ImageIcon iconNewFile = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "new.png"));
        Action actionNew = new MyAction("New Java File", iconNewFile, KeyEvent.VK_J, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        fileMenu.add(actionNew);
//        newMenu.add(actionNew);

//        fileMenu.add(newMenu);
        // Action for Open Project
        ImageIcon iconOpen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "openpack.png"));
        Action actionOpen = new MyAction("Open", iconOpen, KeyEvent.VK_O,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        fileMenu.add(actionOpen);

        // Action for Save Project
        ImageIcon iconSave = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "save.png"));
        Action actionSave = new MyAction("Save", iconSave, KeyEvent.VK_S,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        fileMenu.add(actionSave);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();

        // Action for Exit Project
        ImageIcon iconExit = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "exit.png"));
        Action actionExit = new MyAction("Exit", iconExit, KeyEvent.VK_X,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F4, InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        fileMenu.add(actionExit);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        // Edit menu starts 
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        editMenu.setMnemonic('e');

        // undo action
        ImageIcon iconUndo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "undo.png"));
        Action actionUndo = new MyAction("Undo", iconUndo, KeyEvent.VK_U,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        editMenu.add(actionUndo);

        // redo action
        ImageIcon iconRedo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "redo.png"));
        Action actionRedo = new MyAction("Redo", iconRedo, KeyEvent.VK_R,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Y, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        editMenu.add(actionRedo);
        editMenu.addSeparator();

        // cut action
        ImageIcon iconCut = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "cut.png"));
        Action actionCut = new MyAction("Cut", iconCut, KeyEvent.VK_X,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        editMenu.add(actionCut);

        // copy action
        ImageIcon iconCopy = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "copy.png"));
        Action actionCopy = new MyAction("Copy", iconCopy, KeyEvent.VK_C,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        editMenu.add(actionCopy);

        // paste action
        ImageIcon iconPaste = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "paste.png"));
        Action actionPaste = new MyAction("Paste", iconPaste, KeyEvent.VK_V,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        editMenu.add(actionPaste);
        editMenu.addSeparator();

        // find action
        ImageIcon iconFind = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "find.png"));
        Action actionFind = new MyAction("Find", iconFind, KeyEvent.VK_F,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        editMenu.add(actionFind);

        // Replace action
        ImageIcon iconReplace = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "findreplace.png"));
        Action actionReplace = new MyAction("Replace", iconReplace, KeyEvent.VK_R,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK + InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
        editMenu.add(actionReplace);

        menuBar.add(editMenu);

        // Run menu starts 
        JMenu runMenu = new JMenu("Run");
        runMenu.setMnemonic('r');

        ImageIcon iconRun = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "play.png"));
        Action actionRun = new MyAction("Run", iconRun, KeyEvent.VK_R,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        runMenu.add(actionRun);

        menuBar.add(runMenu);

        // Create toolbar
        toolBar = new JToolBar("File Commands");
        JButton bNewPro = toolBar.add(actionNewProject);
        bNewPro.setToolTipText("New Project");

        JButton bNew = toolBar.add(actionNew);
        bNew.setToolTipText("New Java File");

        JButton bOpen = toolBar.add(actionOpen);
        bOpen.setToolTipText("Open Project");

        JButton bSave = toolBar.add(actionSave);
        bSave.setToolTipText("Save file");

        getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        return menuBar;
    }

    protected String getDocumentName() {
        return currentFile == null ? "Untitled"
                : currentFile.getName();
    }

    protected void newDocument() {
        editor.setText("");
        currentFile = null;
        setTitle(APP_NAME + " [" + getDocumentName() + "]");
        textChanged = false;
        editor.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new UpdateListener());
    }

    protected void openDocument() {
        if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(MainScreen.this)
                != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            return;
        }
        File f = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        if (f == null || !f.isFile()) {
            return;
        }
        currentFile = f;
        try {
            FileReader in = new FileReader(currentFile);
            editor.read(in, null);
            in.close();
            setTitle(APP_NAME + " [" + getDocumentName() + "]");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            showError(ex, "Error reading file " + currentFile);
        }
        textChanged = false;
        editor.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new UpdateListener());
    }

    protected boolean saveFile() {
        if (currentFile == null) {
            if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(MainScreen.this)
                    != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                return false;
            }
            File f = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            if (f == null) {
                return false;
            }
            currentFile = f;
            setTitle(APP_NAME + " [" + getDocumentName() + "]");
        }

        try {
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter(currentFile);
            editor.write(out);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            showError(ex, "Error saving file " + currentFile);
            return false;
        }
        textChanged = false;
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean promptToSave() {
        if (!textChanged) {
            return true;
        }
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
                "Save changes to " + getDocumentName() + "?",
                APP_NAME, JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        switch (result) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                if (!saveFile()) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                return true;
            case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void updateEditor() {
        editor.repaint();
    }

    public void showError(Exception ex, String message) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                message, APP_NAME,
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }

    public void disableAll() {
        fileTree.setEnabled(false);
        fileTreeScroll.setEnabled(false);
        textAreaPane.setEnabled(false);
        outputPane.setEnabled(false);
        textEditor.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void showNewProDialog() {
        System.out.println("Action event of New Project button.");
        NewProject dialogPro = new NewProject(frame, true);
        System.out.println(dialogPro.getSize());
        dialogPro.setVisible(true);
        if (dialogPro.getSucceeded()) {
            log.setText("Status : Creating Files . . .");
dialogPro.getPackName(), dialogPro.getClName());
controller.getClassName(0), controller.getCode(0));

        addTab(dialogPro.getClName(), dialogPro.getClName());
        projectName = dialogPro.getProName();
            Thread work = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    createNewPro(dialogPro.getProName(), dialogPro.getPackName(), dialogPro.getClName());
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            updateTab(0,controller.getCode(0));
                            setFileTree();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            work.start();

        }
    }

    private void createNewPro(String proName, String packName, String clName) {
        controller.createNewProject(proName, packName, clName);
        log.setText("Status : " + controller.getMessage());
    }


    private void updateTab(int index, String text){

        Component comp = textAreaPane.getComponentAt(index);
        if (comp instanceof JScrollPane) {
            JScrollPane pane = (JScrollPane) comp;
            Component comp2 = pane.getComponent(0);
            JViewport viewport = pane.getViewport();  
            if(viewport.getView() instanceof JEditorPane){
                JEditorPane edit = (JEditorPane) viewport.getView();
                edit.setText(text);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addTab(String name, String desc) {
        // TODO think about the text or direct from file
        JEditorPane edit = new JEditorPane();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(edit);
        edit.setContentType("text/java");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH + "new16.gif"));
        textAreaPane.addTab(name, icon, scrollPane, desc);
        textAreaPane.setTabComponentAt(textAreaPane.getComponentCount()-1,new ButtonTabComponent(textAreaPane,icon));
    }

    private void setFileTree(){
        DefaultTreeModel model;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Projects");
        top.add(FileHandling.listFiles(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(projectName), Config.getPath()+projectName, ".java"));
        model = new DefaultTreeModel(top);
        fileTree = new JTree(model);
        fileTreeScroll.setViewportView(fileTree);
        horSplit.setLeftComponent(fileTreeScroll);
    }

    public void showNewFileDialog() {
        System.out.println("Action event of New File button.");
        NewJavaFile dialogFile = new NewJavaFile(frame, true);
        System.out.println(dialogFile.getSize());
        dialogFile.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showOpenProDialog() {
        System.out.println("Action event of open button.");
        OpenProject dialogOpen = new OpenProject(frame, true);
        dialogOpen.setVisible(true);
        if (dialogOpen.getNewClicked()) {
            showNewProDialog();
        }
    }


    class UpdateListener implements DocumentListener {

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            textChanged = true;
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            textChanged = true;
        }

        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            textChanged = true;
        }
    }

    private class MyAction extends AbstractAction {

        String name;

        public MyAction(String name, Icon icon) {
            super(name, icon);
            this.name = name;
        }

        public MyAction(String name, Icon icon,
                Integer mnemonic, KeyStroke accelorator) {
            super(name, icon);
            putValue(Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
            putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, accelorator);
            this.name = name;
        }

        public MyAction(String name, Icon icon, String desc,
                Integer mnemonic, KeyStroke accelorator) {
            super(name, icon);
            putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
            putValue(Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
            putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, accelorator);
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            switch (name) {
                case "New Project":
                    showNewProDialog();
                    break;
                case "New Java File":
                    showNewFileDialog();
                    break;
                case "Open":
                    showOpenProDialog();
                    break;
                case "Save":
                    System.out.println("Action event of save button.");
                    break;
                case "Exit":
                    System.out.println("Action event of exit button.");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                case "Undo":
                    System.out.println("Action event of Undo button.");
                    break;
                case "Redo":
                    System.out.println("Action event of Redo button.");
                    break;
                case "Cut":
                    System.out.println("Action event of Cut button.");
                    break;
                case "Copy":
                    System.out.println("Action event of Copy button.");
                    break;
                case "Paste":
                    System.out.println("Action event of Paste button.");
                    break;
                case "Find":
                    System.out.println("Action event of Find button.");
                    break;
                case "Replace":
                    System.out.println("Action event of Replace button.");
                    break;
                case "Run":
                    System.out.println("Action event of Run button.");
                    compileCode();
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good, that you think about architecture of your program. The answer to your question is MVC pattern. Probably [this](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2013/07/20/the-mvc-pattern-implemented-with-java-swing/) link will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private class MyAction extends AbstractAction
```

will have a reference to MainScreen.this object. That is why you can call it from inside the MyAction class.  when you move it to a new file, you no longer have access to MainScreen.this.

When you pull out the MyAction class to a new file, give it a constructor that takes in a MainScreen object (or better yet, an interface that MainScreen implements) and save it off in a member var. For example, the interface will have the method `showNewFileDialog();`

Then, call methods on that member var, forexample `mainScreen.showNewFileDialog()`

With this implementation, you can reuse your MyAction class

Example MyAction class:

```
public class MyAction extends AbstractAction {

    String name;

    MainScreen mainScreen;

    public MyAction(String name, Icon icon, MainScreen s) {
        super(name, icon);
        this.name = name;
        this.mainScreen = s;
    }

    public MyAction(String name, Icon icon,
            Integer mnemonic, KeyStroke accelorator,) {
        super(name, icon);
        putValue(Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, accelorator);
        this.name = name;
        this.mainScreen = s;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (name) {
            case "New Project":
                mainScreen.showNewProDialog();
                break;
            case "New Java File":
                mainScreen.showNewFileDialog();
                break;
            case "Open":
                showOpenProDialog();
                break;
            case "Save":
                System.out.println("Action event of save button.");
                break;
            case "Exit":
                System.out.println("Action event of exit button.");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case "Undo":
                System.out.println("Action event of Undo button.");
                break;
            case "Redo":
                System.out.println("Action event of Redo button.");
                break;
            case "Cut":
                System.out.println("Action event of Cut button.");
                break;
            case "Copy":
                System.out.println("Action event of Copy button.");
                break;
            case "Paste":
                System.out.println("Action event of Paste button.");
                break;
            case "Find":
                System.out.println("Action event of Find button.");
```

Comment: thanks for answer but MainScreem extends jframe and it shows the main interface to user while myAction class is used to add menuitem and toolbar with single instance how i will separate it and define a var of MainScreen in it

Comment: i updated my response to show you how to refer to the MainScreen object  inside your MyAction class

Comment: thanks once again what about MainScreen class what are the changes in it

Comment: what about tabbed panes i have used how to handle them also

Comment: Let the compiler help you. Implement the changes i showed above in your MyAction class and remove that class from the MainScreen file. then the compiler will show you errors on the lines that need extra stuff (when you create new instances of MyAction)